# Did Ramanuja or Shankara mention the sattvic-rajsic-tamasic purana dichotomy in their works?

Tags: puranas, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya, classification

Padma purana classifies puranas according to gunas, but is this classification mentioned by Shankara or Ramanuja?

Comment: What matters? Neither were omniscient.

Comment: @Rohith. They did have a great intellect.

Comment: this post is only advancing divisiveness - given what modern scholarship has had to say about this.

Comment: @SK modern scholarship claims that whole Vedas are nothing more than useless hymns, they claim purusha sukta to be interpolation, Indra to be supreme and many other nonsense ideas, I think you shouldn't use excuse of modern scholarship for divinely inspired scriptures.

Comment: a close relative who has passed away read the Siva Purana every day.  for poster to sling mud on non-existent "tamasic puranas" is very saddening.

Comment: @SK my mother reads shiva purana too, I'm not degrading any purana I am just asking a question based on historical ideas of Hinduism.

Comment: @SK and don't tell me that shiva centered sites don't claim that bhagvata purana is a false puranas and other such stuff, here we are discussing beliefs, you have yourself claimed many of the scriptures to be mythology, that must hurt other people too you know, calling ramayana myth and stuff like that. Don't get emotional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, both Adi Shankaracharya and Ramanujacharya believed in it.** Here is what Adi Shankaracharya says in verse 371 of the Sarva Vedanta Siddhanta Sara:

> By listening to Sattvic Puranas, by eating Sattvic food, and by serving Sadhus, one increases Sattva Guna.

And here is what Ramanujacharya says in [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48174.htm) of the Sri Bhashyaa:

> And as to the third point, Hiranyagarbha himself is only an individual soul, and hence liable to be overpowered by the inferior gunas, i.e. passion and darkness; and hence the Yoga-smriti is founded on error, no less than the Purânas, promulgated by him, which are founded on ragas and tamas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73838/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-did-ramanuja-or-shankara-mention-the-s).

Comment: "Sattvik" in the Sankara quote is ABSOLUTELY WRONG.  IT is "satva- purana'".  satva is not satvika and purana is not purana in the sense of 18 puranas it is just used in the sense of katha.  So Sankara is only lauding listening to "sat katha" - not "satvika purana".

Comment: @SK That is just a distinction between noun and adjective.  And there is no reason to assume that Purana has any other meaning than the texts known as the Puranas.

Comment: you need to show sankara EVER unequivocally endorsed the guna-based categorization of puranas.  If he didn't then only the everyday meaning of satva can be taken.  will you at least have the goodness to change sattvik to satva in your answer? @keshav srinivasan

Comment: @SK That is precisely the purpose of my answer, to show just that.  And as I said, that is just a noun vs. adjective distinction.

Comment: by the rules of this board your answer is not an answer,  Even conceding your claim there is no proof that sankara believed there are tamasic and rajasic puranas @keshav srinivasan

Comment: Yes @SK it's not an answer. Ramanujas' verse also doesn't tell anything.

Comment: This is a misquote of Adi Sankaracharya. It does not equate to Sankaracharya believing in satvic, rajasic and tamasic puranas.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/vedartha_sangraha_.pdf

"Thus  the  (Vishnu-Purana) exhibits itself as meant solely for the declaration of the determinate identity of the supreme Brahman.
158.  All  other  Puranas  with  other  aims  must  be  interpreted  consistently  with  this  Purana.

That they have other aims is discerned in the manner of their commencement. Whatever is found  in  them,  altogether  inconsistent  with  this Purana must  be  set  aside  as  being  of  the nature of tamas"

from the above quote from the vedartha sangraha it looks like ramanuja regarded vishnu purana as purely sattvik and other puranas that have the same aim as the VP as Sattvik also.  Puranas that do not share the aim of the VP would be judged by content not the whole purana: any content in such Puranas in disagreement with the VP would be tamasic, according to him.