# Do Gaudiya vaishnavas accept classification of puranas based on gunas?

Tags: puranas, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Some vaishnavas use the classification of puranas into sattva, rajas and tamas. Do Gaudiya vaishnavas accept classification of puranas based on three gunas?

Comment: I am a Vasihnava and do not accept such classification. Please don't speak about whole Vasihnava community by listening to only few. In fact I would go one more step and claim nothing like Vasihnava exist. I pray to Lord Vishnu. Am I a Vasihnava? My friend prays to Lord Ganesha. Who is he?

Comment: Yeah, Gaudiya Vaishnavas do

Comment: @Lokesh He's talking specifically about Gaudiya Vaishnavas lol

Comment: @Lokesh Btw you might be interested in this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24158/did-ramanuja-or-shankara-mention-the-sattvic-rajsic-tamasic-purana-dichotomy-in/24695#24695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Gaudiya Vaishnavas accept the guna-based classification of the Puranas. This is what Jiva Goswami states in his "Sri Tattva Sandarba":

> *yad uktam matsye:
>   pancangam ca puranam syad akhyanam itarat smrtam sattvikesu ca kalpesu mahatmyam adhikam hareh
>   rajasesu ca mahatmyam adhikam brahmano viduh
>   tadvad agnes ca mahatmyam tamasesu sivasya ca
>   sankirnesu sarasvatyah pitrnam ca nigadyate*
>
> As the Matsya Purana [53.65, 68 — 69] states, "A historical text is
>   a Purana if it has the five defining characteristics; otherwise it is known as an
>   akhyana. **In Puranas describing days of Brahma in the mode of goodness, the
>   Supreme Lord Hari is mostly glorified. In those describing days in the mode of
>   passion, there is especially glorification of Brahma. In those describing days in the
>   mode of ignorance, there is glorification of Agni and of Siva. In those describing
>   mixed days Sarasvati and the Pitas are discussed.** (**Sri Tattva Sandarba 17.3**)
>
> *atragnes tat-tad-agnau pratipadyasya tat-tad-yaj -nasyety arthah sivasya ceti ca karacchivayas ca. sankirnesu sattva raj as tamo mayesu kalpesu bahusu. sarasvatya nana
>   vany-atmaka-tad-upalaksitaya nana-devataya ity arthah pitrnam karmana pitr
>   lokah iti srutes tat-prapaka karmanam ity arthah.*
>
> **Here glorification "of Agni [the fire-god]" means of Vedic
>   sacrifices which are executed with offerings into various sacred fires. In the phrase
>   "and of Siva also," the word "also" implies "also of Siva [his wife]." "During mixed
>   days" means during the many days of Brahma in which goodness, passion and
>   ignorance are all prominent. "Of Sarasvati" means of various gods who are
>   indirectly indicated by reference to her, since she is the presiding deity of various
>   kinds of verbal expression. "Of the Pitas [celestial forefathers]" means of the ritual
>   activities which lead to attaining them, in accordance with the sruti statement, "By
>   Vedic rituals one achieves the world of the Pitas."** (**Sri Tattva Sandarba 17.4**)
>
> *tad evam sati tat-tat-kalpa -katha-mayatvenaiva matsya eva prasiddhanam tat-tat-purananam vyavasthajnapita taratamyam tu katham syad yenetara-nirnayah kriyeta.
>   sattvadi-taratamyenaiveti cet sattvat sanjayatejnanam iti sattvamyad brahma-darsanam iti ca nyayat sattvikam eva puranadikam paramartha jnanaya prabalam ity
>   ayatam.*
>
> **Such being the facts, we can understand that the Puranas
>   mentioned in the Matsya Purana are divided into natural categories according the
>   kinds of days of Brahma they contain narrations of.** But how can we define a hierarchy of these categories to determine which is superior? It might be suggested
>   that this can be done with a hierarchy of the modes of nature — goodness, passion
>   and ignorance. **If so, we can conclude that Puranas and other scriptures in the
>   mode of goodness have the most authority to teach us about transcendental reality,
>   according to the reasoning of such statements as "From the mode of goodness
>   knowledge develops" EBg. 14.17] and "In the mode of goodness one can realize the
>   Absolute Truth" [Bhag 1..2.24].** (**Sri Tattva Sandarba 18.1**)